# Let $4$ and $5$ be the only eigenvalues of $T$. Show $T^2-9T + 20I = 0$ , T is self adjoint.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be a self adjoint operator on a finite dimensional inner product space. And let $4$ and $5$ be the only eigenvalues of $T$.
Show $T^2-9T + 20I = 0$ .

proof:Let $T$ be a self adjoint. And let $4 , 5$ be the only eigenvalues of $T$.
Then $Tv = 4v, Tv = 5v$ for some $v \neq 0$.
Then $Tv = 4v, Tv = 5v$ if and only if $(T-4I)v = 0, (T-5I)v=0$.

Then $ (T-4I) (T-5I)v=0$ implies $(T^2 -5T -4T + 20I^2)v = 0$, implies

$(T^2 -9T + 20I)v = 0$, so we have  $T^2 -9T + 20I = 0 
$.
Can someone please check this? if it's not correct, could I please have some help on it? Thank you

Comment: It looks okay to me.

Comment: Are you claiming $Tv = 4v$ and $Tv = 5v$ for the same $v$?

Comment: I wasn't really sure about this part. But yes

Comment: How do you know $T^2-9T+10=0$? I think we only know $v$ is in the nullspace of $T^2-9T+10$. I think there is more to do. You haven't used anything about 4 and 5 being the only eigenvalues or being self-adjoint.

Comment: @Mahidevran You can only claim that $Tv_1 = 4v_1$ and $Tv_2 = 5v_2$ for some nonzero $v_1, v_2$. It isn't true that $v_1 = v_2$. You could then prove that $T^2 - 9T + 20I$ takes both $v_1$ and $v_2$ to zero. But to prove an operator is zero, you have to show it takes every vector to zero.

Comment: So I have to show  if $T$ is self adjoint $T=T*$ and $<Tv,v> = 0$ for all $v$, then $T = 0$? So for $Tv_1=4v_1$ and $Tv_2 = 5v_2$ we need to show $<Tv_1,v_1> = <4v_1,v_1> = 0$, similarly for $<Tv_2,v_2> = <5v_2,v_2>$? so that T = 0$

Answer (score 3):

Let $A=T^2-9T + 20I$ and let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$. Then there is an eigenvalue $\mu$ of $T$ such that $\lambda= \mu^2-9 \mu+20$. Since $4$ and  $5$ are the only eigenvalues ot $T$, we get $ \lambda =0$. Since $A$ is selfadjoint, $A$ is diagonalizable. This gives $A=0$